# How can I set presistent cookies on node.js with express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I want to create preistent cookies so that the user of my app doesn't have to login every time he enters the web. But instead, just require log in if he/she ever logs out. Basically, I would like to know if there is a way to set maxAge to infinity(equivalent) and the cookies to persist even if the user closes the browser.
Here is my code:

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: '',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
     secure: false,
     expires: false,
 }
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the standards, you cannot set it to infinity:

> Max-Age=value
>         OPTIONAL.  The value of the Max-Age attribute is delta-seconds,
>         the lifetime of the cookie in seconds, a decimal non-negative
>         integer.  To handle cached cookies correctly, a client SHOULD
>         calculate the age of the cookie according to the age calculation
>         rules in the HTTP/1.1 specification [RFC2616].  When the age is
>         greater than delta-seconds seconds, the client SHOULD discard the
>         cookie.  A value of zero means the cookie SHOULD be discarded
>         immediately.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html

But as an alternative you can safely set the age to 5 years or 10 years later. Most probably a user would get rid of his device/PC/Mobile by this time. :)

Update:
To set the expiry time in future you can use MaxAge as following, setting it to expiry in a month:

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: '',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  rolling: true,
  cookie: {
     secure: false,
     maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
 }
}))
```

This would set it to expiry

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I potentially set a cookie's age to me a month, but every time that the user is in the web then, reset the count. So the age is back to one month instead to 1 month minus time since the login?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but if the user didn't login with a month, then the cookies will expire.

Comment: How do I configure that? Is that the resave:false parameter?

Comment: You need to enable rolling for the maxAge so that it is updated with every request. I have not tested this code right now, but this should put you in the right direction.